# Codes don't take effect

Tags: jquery

I have the same template on two websites (WordPress). I downloaded a Custom Javascript plugin and added the following code:

```
$("#wrapfirst").removeClass("fadeInUp pagewrap1");
$("#wrapsecond").removeClass("fadeInLeft pagewrap2");
```

One website applied the changes and the other didn't. The one that did is www.shawneegaragedoors.com and the one that didn't (still has fadein effects) is www.madisongaragerepair.com

I also tried a different thing that worked on the Shawnee website but not on the Madison one. I deleted the following from the custom.js file:

```
//CSS Animation
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    jQuery('.pagewrap1').each(function(){
        var imagePos = jQuery(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                jQuery(this).addClass("fadeInUp");
            }
        });

    jQuery('.pagewrap2').each(function(){
        var imagePos = jQuery(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                jQuery(this).addClass("fadeInLeft");
            }
        });

     jQuery('.postwrap3').each(function(){
        var imagePos = jQuery(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                jQuery(this).addClass("fadeInRight");
            }
        }); 


});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.srchicon').click(function() {
            jQuery('.searchtop').toggle();
            jQuery('.topsocial').toggle();
        }); 
});
```

Then, I deleted:

```
.pagewrap1, .pagewrap2, .postwrap3{ visibility: hidden;}
```

from the style.css.

In both cases, only the Shawnee website changed.

Can anyone help me out with this? I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the source code in your browser on the Madison site, do you see your changes?  Be sure to refresh your browser first.  If not, you're editing the wrong file or saving your edits to the wrong place.

Comment: I did a refresh and also cleared cache from both browser and website. I did exactly the same things on both websites. When I change certain things on the Madison website the changes apply, but not all them.